# Refactoring apply from buildscript when moving from groovy to kts

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have android project where I am trying to move from groovy to kts.

In the top-level build.gradle file I have this section

```
buildscript {
    apply { from(rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle.kts")) }
...
}
```

How do I refactor this apply when moving from groovy to kts?

The version.gradle.kts itself contains stuff like

```
val okhttpVersion = "4.9.3"
extra["okhttp"] = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
```

which then I want to reference as

```
dependencies {
    implementation(rootProject.ext.okhttp)
}
```

I have done "searches" on SO to see if there is hint on how to use `apply from` and initializing version & package name map and then use it. Perhaps I am not searching for right term. Would appreciate any pointers! ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just refactor your apply block like this:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    apply(from = rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle.kts"))
    // ...
}
```

And use implementation like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(rootProject.extra["okhttp"] as String)
}
```